# HTTP request forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: .net, windows, web-services, client-certificates, trusted

I am trying to access a web service from a C# application.

I have been given a client certificate from the web service provider which I have installed into Windows.

The response I get from the web service is:

**The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.**

What is the likely reason for this response?

Is it because my client certificate is not *"trusted"* by the server hosting the web service?

Comment: Is this a WCF service, old-style ASP.NET ASMX web-service, the new ASP.NET Web API platform, or something else?

Comment: @Dai : I don't know what type of web-service it is. The HTTP response says it is from a "WebSEAL" server.